# Getting a boost::filesystem::path as an UTF-8 encoded std::string, on Windows

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, boost-filesystem

We are representing paths as `boost::filesystem::path`, but in some cases other APIs are expecting them as `const char *` (e.g., to open a DB file with SQLite).

From [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path), `path::value_type` is a `wchar_t` under Windows. As far as I know, Windows `wchar_t` are 2 bytes, UTF-16 encoded.

There is a [`string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers) native observer that returns a `std::string`, while stating:

> If string_type is a different type than String, conversion is
>   performed by cvt.

`cvt` is initialized to a default constructed `codecvt`. What is the behaviour of this default constructed codecvt?

There is [this forum entry](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-filesystem-path-as-utf-8-tp4320098p4322460.html), that recommends to use an instance of `utf8_codecvt_facet` as the `cvt` value to portably convert to UTF-8. But it seems that this codecvt is actually to convert [between UTF-8 and UCS-4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html), not UTF-16.

What would be the best way (and if possible portable) to obtain an `std::string` representation of a `path`, making sure to convert from the right `wchar_t` encoding when necessary?

Answer (score 9):

> cvt is initialized to a default constructed codecvt. What is the
>   behaviour of this default constructed codecvt?

It uses the default locale for conversion to the locale-specific multi-byte character set. On Windows this locale normally corresponds to the regional settings in the control panel.

> What would be the best way (and if possible portable) to obtain an
>   std::string representation of a path, making sure to convert from the
>   right wchar_t encoding when necessary?

The C++11 standard introduced [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16). Although it is deprecated as of `C++17`, according to [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html) it will be available "until a suitable replacement is standardized".

To use this facet, call the static function:

```
boost::filesystem::path::imbue( 
    std::locale( std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>() ) );
```

After that all calls to `path::string()` will convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Another way is to use `std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t> >` to do the conversion only in some cases.

Complete example code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>

void print_hex( std::string const& path );

int main()
{
    // Create UTF-16 path (on Windows) that contains the characters "ÄÖÜ".
    boost::filesystem::path path( L"\u00c4\u00d6\u00dc" );

    // Convert path using the default locale and print result.
    // On a system with german default locale, this prints "0xc4 0xd6 0xdc".
    // On a system with a different locale, this might fail.
    print_hex( path.string() );

    // Set locale for conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8.
    boost::filesystem::path::imbue( 
        std::locale( std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>() ) );

    // Because we changed the locale, path::string() now converts the path to UTF-8.
    // This always prints the UTF-8 bytes "0xc3 0x84 0xc3 0x96 0xc3 0x9c".
    print_hex( path.string() );

    // Another option is to convert only case-by-case, by explicitly using a code converter.
    // This always prints the UTF-8 bytes "0xc3 0x84 0xc3 0x96 0xc3 0x9c".
    std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t> > cvt;
    print_hex( cvt.to_bytes( path.wstring() ) );
}

void print_hex( std::string const& path )
{
    for( char c : path )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>( c )) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This `path.imbue` call is misleading - `boost::filesystem::path::imbue` is a static function affecting global state, not the `path` variable per se.

Comment: @sms Good catch. I've changed to `::` notation and explicited mention that it's a static function.

Comment: C++1x is not a standard. Did you mean C++11? Or did you mean C++11 & C++14 & C++17? Please clarify.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Done.